# Java. Method in generics class always return Object

Tags: java, generics

I have Matrix abstract class:

```
public abstract class Matrix<T> implements Cloneable {
  public abstract void set(Long row, Long col, T val);
  public abstract Set<Long> getRows();
  public abstract Set<Long> getCols(Long row);
  public abstract T get(Long row, Long col);
  ..
```

This is part of implementation:

```
public class SparseMatrix<T> extends Matrix<T> {
  private Map<Long, Map<Long, T>> matrix = new HashMap<Long, Map<Long, T>>();
  private Size size;
  T notObservedValue = null;

  public SparseMatrix(Size size){
      this.size = size;
  }

  public void setNotObservedValue(T value){
      notObservedValue = value;
  }
  @Override
  public void set(Long row, Long col, T val){
    if( matrix.containsKey(row) )
        matrix.get(row).put(col, val);
    else{
        Map<Long, T> cols = new HashMap<Long, T>();
        cols.put(col, val);
        matrix.put(row, cols);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Long> getRows(){
      return matrix.keySet();
  }
  @Override
  public Set<Long> getCols(Long row){
      return matrix.get(row).keySet();
  }

  @Override
  public T get(Long row, Long col){
     Map<Long, T> r = matrix.get(row);
    if(r != null){
        T result = r.get(col);
        if(result == null)
            return notObservedValue;
        return result;
    }
    return notObservedValue;
  }
```

When I trying to iterate each value in the sparse matrix this code does not work:

```
  for(Long row : matrix.getRows()){
     for(Long col : matrix.getCols(row)){
        continue;
     }
  }
```

Error is

> java: incompatible types
>     required: java.lang.Long
>     found:    java.lang.Object

It is solving by use manual casting:

```
for(Long row : (Set<Long>)matrix.getRows()){
  for(Long col : (Set<Long>)matrix.getCols(row)){
    continue;
  }
}
```

But I dont understand, why return value type is Object? It is not generics-method, this method declared as Set getRows() in Matrix abstract class and in SparseMatrix implementation.

Comment: How do you instantiate the Matrix which you iterate?

Comment: SparseMatrix matrix = new SparseMatrix<Double>(new Size(3, 2));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't instantiated **correctly** the `matrix` object. It has to be (for example):

```
SparseMatrix<Double> matrix = new SparseMatrix<Double>(new Size(3, 2));
```

The reason is that when you instantiate objects by using their **raw types**, all the generic information is erased (which mean that every generic piece in your code will be replaced by its raw variant). Therefore, when you do `SparseMatrix matrix = ...` the generic methods will be converted (for example) to:

```
@Override
public Set getRows(){
    return matrix.keySet();
}
@Override
public Set getCols(Long row){
    return matrix.get(row).keySet();
}
```

A raw `Set` is the same as `Set<Object>` which explains why the compiler forces you to do casts.

For further details see [the documentation on raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: Yes, this really works. Thanks. But why I need to describe type of generic if this method does not depends on Generic-Type?

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for this?

Comment: You can check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) link and note the sentence *When using raw types, you essentially get pre-generics behavior...*